# JSTL: Does Object Exist

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

When building my webpage using JSTL, certain objects might be passed into the JSP view and some may not. The Java business logic will determine whether or not the object is required.

In the JSP, what is the best way to check if the object has been passed in or not. Should I do a null test? Should I have a "pageContents" list which contains all the objects the page uses and check if the object is in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a single object, IMO, but not a list, an actual object. Personally, I'd use additional methods to indicate if the individual items are present or not, as the logic could be more complex than present or not, e.g., business logic. This is basically the presenter pattern.

Comment: So let's say I am dealing with Product objects? Do you mean I pass in a Products object which has a hasProducts flag; and another collection member which stores any possible Product objects. Then in my JSP, I test products.hasProducts() and if so, iterate through the collection? Is that right?

Comment: If you have a list of products, pass a list. Pass an empty list if no products. I was referring to an overall design, instead of passing in many objects, pass in an object specific to that view.

Comment: OK, I think I get it. Just as another example, assume each Product has a contact member. The generated HTML as it would appear in the browser would be "Contact: Joe Bloggs". However, if a Product has no contact, I don't want that section to appear at all. I don't want "Contact: " to be outputted. So therefore, I have to test for the existence of a contact before I output the label "Contact: ". So for that example, would I use <c:if test="${empty product.contact}">

Comment: I'd wrap it up in a decorator that provides a boolean "showContact()" method to avoid relying on simple presence. Optionally use a custom tag that wraps up the check and the label + value output. My goal is usually to make the view later as drop dead simple to read as possible.

Comment: I fully agree that the view should be as simple as possible. However, JSP/JSTL is still new to me and I'm unsure how to implement your (1) decorator / showContact() or (2) custom tags that contain both label and value. An example of both would be very welcome, if possible.

Comment: A decorator is just a class that wraps another class (e.g., composition) and adds/modifies functionality. In this case it might provide a `showContact` method that determines if the wrapping HTML should be views. It might also have a `contactForDisplay` method that would include the "Contact: [firstName] [lastName]" string etc. There are any number of ways to do all this, though.